Replace smartsheet with smartsheetr package
I am trying to read a smartsheet using smartsheetr package by @colej1390 and replace the samesheet with new data for next month with the same name/id. I tried it with a mtcars data set and it works. but, when I use my data which has ~4000 rows smartsheetr::ss_replace_sheet() throws an error
Error in `ss_api()`: ! Unknown content type
this is the code I am trying,
data = smartsheetr::ss_read_sheet('smartsheet_data')
data = as.data.frame(data)
sample = data %>% head(2)
newdata = rbind(data,sample)
smartsheetr::ss_replace_sheet('smartsheet_data' ,data=newdata)'''

Does anybody know why this error occurs? this happens with ss_delete_rows() too.

